# Decode using available method for encoding in VB

Tags: vb.net, decode, encode

I have this method

```
Public Shared Function HashPassword(ByVal password As String) As String

        Dim algorithm As HashAlgorithm
        algorithm = SHA1.Create
        Dim data As Byte() = algorithm.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password))
        Dim HashedPassword As String = ""
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Do While i < data.Length
            HashedPassword &= data(i).ToString("x2").ToLowerInvariant()
            i += 1
        Loop
        Return HashedPassword

    End Function
```

How can I decode a string which has been encoded by this function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unhashing a hash C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501230/unhashing-a-hash-c-sharp)

Comment: Usually the result (`data`) is converted to Base64: `hash = Convert.ToBase64String(data)`  not sure what you are doing there will work

Comment: You can't. That is the whole point of a `Hash`.

Answer (score 1):

A hash is a one way so you dont decrypt them.  Instead, compare the new input value to the stored hash to verify.  If you want to encrypt/decrypt data (*not* the best way to protect passwords), then you need to encrypt, not hash.

But there may be a problem with your method: the result is usually converted to base64 for storing/saving.  A hex string might work (never tried) but there is a built in way for this:

```
Public Shared Function HashPassword(password As String) As String

    Dim algorithm As HashAlgorithm
    algorithm = SHA1.Create
    Dim data As Byte() = algorithm.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password))

    Return Convert.ToBase64String(data)

End Function
```

So, new user registration would be something like:

```
hashedPW = HashPassword(thePWText)
```

To check it later:

```
thisPW = HashPassword(PWInput)

If thisPW = hashedPW Then
   ' user knows the PW
Else
   ' wrong password
End If
```